# Swift with Parse - Apple Mach-O Linker Error with already include Bolts.Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm really new to Swift as well as Parse. 
I'm using xCode 6.1 with Parse ver 1.6.0

What I did in my project is that I try to add application key and client key to my project and test if it's working or not. But I got error while compile.
[Here's how it looks like](http://juntima.me/swift.png)

I've already added Bolts.Framework to my project as there are so many people suggested it.
[Here's how is my file structure looks like](http://juntima.me/swift2.png)

I wonder how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: try adding `libsqlite3.dylib` to your project

Answer (score 0):

Go to App Project -> Build phases -> Put the Bolts framework above other imported frameworks. Also add libsqlite3.dylib.